# Correct file upload folder permission

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, permissions

In [CI user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) there is such line:

> You'll need a destination folder for your uploaded images. Create a
>   folder at the root of your CodeIgniter installation called uploads and
>   set its file permissions to 777.

How secure is it when I am developing real web application? For example: social network and I want to upload user's profile pictures. I think I will have privacy problems when user's will want to upload private pictures.

Comment: Keep the upload folder out of the public access. Then make a controller method that retrieves the file again as described here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/download_helper.html - The benefit is also that you can control who is downloading what file more secure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

depending on the level of security you want, 777 might not be the best option (it's the simplest). The user the webserver runs as much have rwx to the folder, and if you want to be truly secure, the folder should not be under your webroot.

That means, if the web files are in /home/mysite/ ( eg /home/mysite/index.html maps to http://mydomain.com/index.html ) then the upload folder should be /home/uploads .

You application can use code to access the files via the system path ( /home/uploads ) but noone from the internet can directly access it that way.

Alternatively, if you cannot do the above ( eg because you're on a shared host ) you can use `.htaccess` (placed in the upload folder) for the same effect, by placing these rules :

```
Deny from all
Options None
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

( note that again, your app will need to use the system path, since Apache wont be able to serve these files directly ).

Answer (score 1):

You could also use .htaccess to deny access to folders except those that you permit. At least I did same with mine and directories that are not listed for access in the .htaccess are not available to users.

Another safe way is to use a folder outside /public_html/
Directories outside this folder can hardly be accessed externally.